# Dart Variable store reference to the value

Tags: javascript, dart

I just started learning about Dart.

Before Dart, I worked with Javascript and have some experience.

Now, as I was going through the [documentation from Tutorial Point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dart_programming/dart_programming_variables.htm). They have mentioned something like this

> All variables in dart store a reference to the value rather than
> containing the value. The variable called name contains a reference to
> a String object with a value of “Smith”.

In Javascript, I guess arrays and objects are reference types.

Meaning, If we do something like this

**[Update:] This code snippet is incorrect**

```
let a = ["apple", "orange"]

let b = a 

a = ["banana"] 

console.log(b) //["banana"]
```

but that is probably only for objects and arrays in JS (and not for const and let)

```
let a = 5
let b = a 
a = 7
console.log(b) //5
```

From the quote,

> All variables in Dart store a reference to the value

**[Question:]** Does this mean that even things like int, string.. and every variable we create in Dart are references? and the equivalence of the above code will print 7 in Dart or I am getting something wrong (in general)?

```
let a = 5
let b = a 
a = 7
console.log(b) //7
```

Comment: Your example with `["Apple", "orange"]` and then reassigning to `["Banana"]` is _not_ how javascript behaves. In that case `["Apple", "Orange"]` would be logged to the console.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Everything is an Object in Dart. Some objects are mutable - that is they can be modified, and some are immutable, that is they will always be the same value.

When you assign with `var b = a;` both `b` and `a` will reference the same Object, but there is no further association between the names `b` and `a`. If you *mutate* that Object by calling methods on it or assigning to fields on it (things like [`List.add`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-collection/LinkedList/add.html) for example) then you will be able to observe the mutated Object through either name `b` or `a`. If you *assign* to `a` then the variable `b` is unaffected. This is true in javascript as well.

The reason some types, like numbers or Strings, appear special is that they cannot be mutated, so the only way to "change" `a` is to reassign it, which won't impact `b`. Other types, like collections, are mutable and so `a.add("Banana")` would be a mutation visible through either variable referencing that list.

For example, with assignment:

```
var a = ['Apple', 'Orange'];
var b = a;
a = ['Banana']; // Assignment, no impact to b
print(a); // [Banana]
print(b); // [Apple, Orange]
```

With mutation:

```
var a = ['Apple', 'Orange'];
var b = a;
a.clear(); // Mutation, the _list instance_ is changed
a.add('Banana')  // Another mutation
print(a); // [Banana]
print(b); // [Banana]
```

Comment: Hey Nate, 

Clearly I have vague understanding of some concepts of javascript.  It will be a great help if you could explain your answer with some code

Comment: Added some code samples. You can also try out some samples in dartpad - https://dartpad.dartlang.org/