# Variable Independent of setState

Tags: flutter, dart

So say I have a Map and somewhere in my code and I want to save its current state. I set Map Two equal to Map One and go on changing the value of Map One hoping to keep the values of Map Two the same for reference. If I call setState(() {}) after I change Map One it seems to update all values of Map Two as well. This is not what I want. I want to set Map Two and not update until I want to save Map One's state again. It's tough to demonstrate this problem in my code without dumping the whole thing so I'll try to illustrate what I'm talking about below. Just ignore that this code won't actually run, this is the idea. The values of Map Two would be used in a widget but for the sake of example, the value is just being printed. This code would theoretically print foo. I want it to print start. In my mind, there should be something like const or final that I'm just missing that sets a variable and doesn't make it relative.

```
Map mapOne = {
  'start' : 'start',
  'end' : 'end'
};
late Map mapTwo;

main() {
  mapTwo = mapOne;
  mapOne = {
    'start' : 'foo',
    'end' : 'foo'
  };
  
  setState(() {});
  
  print(mapTwo['start']);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54545977/dart-variable-store-reference-to-the-value). The problem is the difference between mutable and immutable variables. For me, the solution was storing the value I needed in a string rather than a map because maps are mutable where strings are not. The post I referenced earlier has more details.

Answer (score 0):

When you're assigning map one to map two, you're basically setting map one and map two to reference the same object. So to achieve what you want you can do this:

```
mapTwo = Map.from(mapOne);
```

Here is an example to verify:

```
void main() async {
  final a = {'a': 'b'};
  final b = Map.from(a);
  b['a'] = 'c';
  print(a);
  print(b);
}
```

Comment: I tested it and it still seems to exhibit the same behavior. Maybe it's simply not possible? I really have no idea but thank you for your answer.

Comment: Then you have other problems. Check my answer again I've provided a simple code for you to verify that it's working correctly this way. @EthanCrosby