# Text widget in Flutter shows same text for all Text widgets in for loop

Tags: flutter, dart

In Flutter, I am using a Text widget in a for loop. The console shows a nice increasing list of numbers. However all 25 Text widgets show 25.

It looks like the Text widget does make a reference to `_markersDistanceCount` instead of using their value.

I've also tried to `jsonEncode` and `jsonDecode` the values, but still they are all 25. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
var _markersDistanceCount = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
  _markersDistanceCount++;
  print(_markersDistanceCount);
  markersDistance.add(
    Marker(
      point: LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude),
      builder: (context) => CircleAvatar(
        radius: 50,
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        child: Text(_markersDistanceCount.toString())
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

When I change `Text(_markersDistanceCount.toString())` to `Text(i.toString())` there is no issue and Text widgets are containing the correct `i` value.

Comment: This function looks good and works in dart pad. How are you using the list in your widget tree do you access elements by index with listview.builder ?

Comment: markersDistance is been used by a flutter_map to show markers on the map. You can just provide the list. It is defined as `List<Marker> markersDistance = [];` which shouldn't be an issue since the markers are correct when using `i` instead of `_markersDistanceCount`

Comment: Can you include widget =>  [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh do you know something like Dart pad which can use external packages? Since I need flutter_map to reproduce.

Comment: I might be wrong, while this is `Text` issue, you can provide a widget, the main thing is where you are generating this data.

Comment: They are generated in a function called from the `initState()`

Comment: Can you try putting unique `Value` for each `Marker`. I've failed to reproduce the issue by removing `Marker`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242175/discussion-between-bas-van-dijk-and-yeasin-sheikh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you end up with all having 25 as Text. The Text() have the same variable the whole time.

### UPDATE:

The `Text(_markersDistanceCount)` you have is all pointing to the same variable, which in the end have the value of 25.

Try this instead:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
  // Either
  final _distanceCount = _markersDistanceCount++;
  // Or rather
  final _distanceCount =  i + 1;

  markersDistance.add(
    Marker(
      point: LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude),
      builder: (context) => CircleAvatar(
        radius: 50,
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        child: Text(_distanceCount.toString())
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: this works! Do you mind to share why I need to use final instead and can't use the var outside the for loop?

Comment: if it is about creating another variable, I will just use `i` as he described on question.

Comment: I've used `final _distanceCount = _markersDistanceCount++;` to make it work. But I am kinda confused why I need to use final.

Comment: I updated my answer @BasvanDijk - you could use `var` or `const` as well. The thing is that you declare _markersDistanceCount outside the for loop and in the end every `Text(_markersDistanceCount)` is pointing to the same variable which has the same value in the end for all the markers.

Comment: So it used "by reference" and with the const or final we make it "by value" right?

Comment: It's pretty good explained on the following link - I hope that helps! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54545977/dart-variable-store-reference-to-the-value

Answer (score 0):

The value of `_markersDistanceCount` becomes 25 before reaching the `Marker`'s `builder` method. To explore it I've debugged the code, here I am using an inline method to show the situation. I am not aware of this type of behavior, just exploring the issue.

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  int _markersDistanceCount = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    _markersDistanceCount++;
    markersDistance.add(
      () {
        debugPrint("OnTop=>  i: $i mkNUm:  ${_markersDistanceCount.toInt()}");
        return Marker(
            key: ValueKey("tm $_markersDistanceCount"),
            point: () {
              debugPrint(
                  "On point=>  i: $i mkNUm:  ${_markersDistanceCount.toInt()}");
              return LatLng(51.5 + (i * .01), -0.09);
            }(),
            builder: (context) {
              ///this gets call after while `_markersDistanceCount:25` completing the loop
              debugPrint(
                  "insideBuild=> i: $i mkNUm:  ${_markersDistanceCount.toInt()}");
              return CircleAvatar(
                radius: 50,
                backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                child: Text(
                  _markersDistanceCount.toDouble().toString(),
                ),
              );
            });
      }(),
    );
  }
}
```

This will print

```
OnTop=>  i: 0 mkNUm:  1
On point=>  i: 0 mkNUm:  1
OnTop=>  i: 1 mkNUm:  2   
On point=>  i: 1 mkNUm:  2
OnTop=>  i: 2 mkNUm:  3   
.....
OnTop=>  i: 24 mkNUm:  25
On point=>  i: 24 mkNUm:  25
insideBuild=> i: 0 mkNUm:  25
insideBuild=> i: 1 mkNUm:  25
```

As for the solution, you can use `i` while both share the same responsibility.

Comment: I am still trying to get this behavior.